# How to open file in VSCode from integrated terminal in a current application window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Now:

```
rudskoy$>: code temp.py
—————> It opens temp.py in a new VS Code window!
```

What I want:

```
rudskoy$>: code temp.py
—————> It opens temp.py in a current window as a new tab
```

Is this behaviour configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've investigate that terminal command (`code`) has an `--help` option.

`--help` says that: `-r, --reuse-window Force opening a file or folder in the last active window.`

This `-r` option is that I want to get from my question.